# Firefox content script not loading in some pages

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

**Context**

I am currently working on a browser extension which is working as expected with Chrome and Opera but I am facing issues with Firefox. Here is a minimal version of `manifest.json` needed to reproduce the problem:

```
{
    "name": "Example",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "Pyves",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "all_frames": true,
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "content.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

And here is the related `content.js`:

```
console.log("Content script loaded");
```

**Issue**

`Content script loaded` is systematically logged regardless of the visited page when using Chrome and Opera. Nevertheless, the content script doesn't seem to load in some pages when using Firefox, for instance raw GitHub pages such as the following:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/badges/shields/master/README.md

There are no error messages in the Firefox console stating why the content script was not executed on that particular page.

**Questions**

- Why is the Firefox extension unable to load the content script into some pages?
- What changes need to be made so that the extension works consistently on all browsers?

Comment: I believe that because that specific page you provide is not a web page but a .md file Firefox is not running you content scripts there.

Comment: @ChristosPapoulas: thank you for your comment. Nevertheless I don't think that is the case. For instance when I try to load a local file within Firefox or a file from a private code repository, it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally figured out why the extension's content script is not loading in some pages when using Firefox.

After analysing the requests with the Network developer tools, it turns out that the following headers are returned when getting GitHub raw pages:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'; sandbox
```

According to the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/sandbox), the `sandbox` CSP directive has the following effect:

> enables a sandbox for the requested resource [...]. It applies
>   restrictions to a page's actions including preventing popups,
>   preventing the execution of plugins and scripts, and enforcing a
>   same-origin policy.

Therefore Firefox is preventing extensions from executing content scripts in pages with the sandbox CSP, whereas other browsers such as Chrome and Opera do allow this behaviour. Related bug reports in Mozilla's Bugzilla ([1267027](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1267027) and [1411641](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1411641)) highlight that:

> CSP 'sandbox' directive prevents content scripts from matching, due to unique origin

This issue has been acknowledged and will hopefully be fixed in future releases of Firefox.

Comment: I also have an add-on and experienced the same. I've been wondering for months why the script wouldn't load, thank you so much for this answer!

Comment: It does also not work without "sandox" for some pages. I have the problem with this page: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/address-bar-autocomplete-firefox
There, no content scripts is loaded.

Comment: For me the problem was different. My extension runs certain scripts on the page load; and for that, in Chrome, I'm using the "onload" event of windows. But this is not supported in firefox due to the new cache feature. In firefox, the onload event gets fired at once, and then its not fired, instead the "pageshow" event it fired, it improves the navigation of firefox. So now, in case of firefox I have totally replaced the "onload" event with the "pageshow" event, and its working fine even on the first load. Hope that helps someone! :)

Comment: It appears that content scripts are not allowed on *.mozilla.org.  BTW, under both Chrome and Opera it seems that content scripts are not allowed on *.google.com.  It is probably some sort of attempt at "protecting" their own websites from attacks via content scripts.  In google's case I sort of understand that, because google search engine, youtube, gmail, etc are all valuable target for attacks via extensions.  But mozilla.org?  probably not so much.

Comment: addons.mozilla.org is how you install extensions in Firefox. Should random extensions be able to modify that page?