# Firefox extension content script does not load during temporary add-on load

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-developer-tools

I'm developing an extension that involves both a background script and a content script. The content script gets the selected text from webpages, when the user clicks on the extension's relative menu entry and then sends it to the background script for further processing.

Here is the relative section of the **manifest.json**:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  
  "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }
]
```

I load the extension in **about:debugging > This Firefox > Load Temporary Add-on...** in order to test it.

In the code I send a message from the background script to the content script but that throws an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving
> end does not exist

I checked by using the Debugger, in **about:devtools-toolbox** and I found out that only the background script loads.

**Does anyone have an idea what makes the content script to fail to load and what would the solution be?**

Comment: That error is to do with how the background and content scripts are communicating with each other, but you haven't added that code so we can't really debug it. Content scripts message the background script with [runtime.sendMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage). Background scripts [message the content scripts differently](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/sendMessage). Did my answer from a couple of days ago not help at all?

Comment: If you have a GH repo I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: No, I'm testing the code locally.
The thing is that the content script does not load at all. Only the background script loads. So communication is impossible in that case and the problem obviously has nothing to do with any possible errors with the messages between the scripts.

The receiving end does not exist, **because the content.js file that implements it does not load.**

Comment: Ok, but I can't debug code that I have no access to.

Comment: Yes, I get that, but I don't think that's a problem of the code in the first place. The relative code that instructs Firefox to load the content script is part of the **manifest.json** file and I have shared the relative snippet. Probably there is nothing wrong with the manifest's code, so there is something else that prevents the script from loading.

Comment: All I can tell you without seeing the extension itself is that it should work assuming your paths to your scripts are correct. I can't make you share your code, but no-one can answer _why_ your content script isn't loading without seeing the code. At this point it's just a guessing game.

Comment: I think guessing that the code prevents itself to load is a guess to the wrong direction. I'm trying to find other similar cases. I have seen this one so far: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47622435/firefox-content-script-not-loading-in-some-pages but it does not apply in my case, since no networking is involved. I have also found this: https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/content-scripts-are-not-loaded-in-firefox-on-some-web-pages/60705/2 but my issue also has nothing to do with restricted URLs. I don't know yet what's the cause, but I'm almost 100% sure that isn't the source code.

Comment: Honestly, I really want to help you to solve this. Can you zip up the files and stick the file on https://file.fm/ or something? At the moment we're not getting anywhere.

Comment: Here you go: https://file.fm/u/uhdmw7qpu
That's a version of the original extension with the functionality of the background script changed, but it keeps the messaging between the scripts and it reproduces the problem of the content script failure. **Does the content script load when you load the extension in your browser? Does it appear in the Sources in the Debugger?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background script should send a message to the content script, asking for the selected text, and then listen to the message it receives. Then it can call the function that does the Google search:

```
function onCreated() {
  if (browser.runtime.lastError) {
    console.log(`Error: ${browser.runtime.lastError}`);
  } else {
    console.log("Item created successfully");
  }
}

browser.menus.create({
  id: "context-entry",
  title: 'search',
  contexts: ['all'],
  onclick: getText
}, onCreated);

async function getText() {
  const tabInfo = await getCurrentTab();
  const [{ id: tabId }] = tabInfo;
  browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { trigger: 'getText' });
}

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function ({ txt }) {
  doSearch(txt);
});

function doSearch(txt) {
  var searchURL = `https://www.google.com/search?q=${txt}`;
  browser.tabs.create({url: searchURL});
}
```

And the content script should listen to the message from the background script, and send the selected text back.

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(({ trigger }) => {
  if (trigger === 'getText') {
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    const txt = selection.toString();
    browser.runtime.sendMessage({ trigger: 'foundText', txt });
  }
});
```

Comment: Well, my original hypothesis that the content script did not load was totally wrong. Still only the background script is visible in the debugger, so I guess that's the default behavior.

Comment: Got there in the end though, didn't we? :)

Comment: You actually did to be honest. A million thanks!

Comment: FWIW it took me ages to write my first add-on. Write some code, look at the documentation, rewrite the code, look at the documentation again, write some new code etc. The API is confusing at first, but once you've created one you have a decent baseline for any more that you want to write. @Costas

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement!
The last time I have coded for a Firefox extension was many years ago, when the XUL overlay was still used. The [current code architecture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension) looks more complicated to me, compared with the previous one, but you're right, everything is a matter of habit.

Comment: [Here's something I wrote last week](https://github.com/andywillis/stackoverflow-helper) that allows me to add bespoke comments and code to SO comments and answers. The boilerplate for the add-on might help you in the future. It requires a new FF profile so I don't have to worry about the add-ons in my main profile, and that's called from `./rundev.sh` in the terminal which is how I could fix your code so quickly. Anyway, good luck with the coding @Costas.

Comment: I have the exact same question, but the above answer doesn't seem to answer the question in any meaningful way. It would appear In my case "Does the content script load when you load the extension in your browser?" - no. "Does it appear in the Sources in the Debugger?" - no. It did in the past, now it does not, something changed in Firefox.

Comment: @GrahamLeggett you should probably post a new question as things may have changed since I answered this in 2021.